# Integer to Float but addProximityAlert not working

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to add a proximity alert in my application but with variable radius.

If I use radius value like this

```
float radius = 100f;
```

It works!

But I'm trying to do it this way:

```
private void setProximityAlert(String Title, double lat, double lon, float radius, final int id, int requestCode){
    // Expiration is 10 Minutes (10mins * 60secs * 1000milliSecs)
    long expiration = 600000;

    LocationManager locManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

    Intent intent = new Intent(PROXIMITY_INTENT_ACTION);
    intent.putExtra("id", id);
    intent.putExtra("Title", Title);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getApplicationContext(), requestCode, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);

    locManager.addProximityAlert(lat, lon, radius, expiration, pendingIntent);
}
```

I'm setting the proximity alerts this way:

```
    this.dh = new DataHelper(ShowMap.this);
    List<Pontos> list = this.dh.selectAll();
    int count = 0;
    for(Pontos p : list){
        markerPlaces.add(new OverlayItem(p.getName().toString(), Integer.toString(p.getId()), new GeoPoint(p.getLat(), p.getLng())));
        setProximityAlert(p.getName().toString(), p.getLat(), p.getLng(), p.getRadius(), p.getId(), count);
        count++;
    }
```

Note: p.getRadius() returns int value...

My problem is that is I use `radius = 100f;` it works fine, so I think I need to convert to float the same way, like the integer value is 10 so the float will be 10f.

Thanks!

Comment: It's really unclear what's going on here. You haven't shown what your method looks like, or the parameter, or how you're calling it, or what error you get. Please read http://tinyurl.com/so-hints

Comment: @JonSkeet Thanks for the tip, I edited the first post, hope you can now understand :)

Comment: Not really - what's the error you're getting?

Comment: The proximity alerts stop working when I don't hardcode the float value like 100f...

Comment: So it's not a compile-time error, but just something not being triggered? (This is why you *must* be clearer with your questions...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be absolutely fine. There's an implicit conversion from `int` to `float`, so if `p.getRadius()` returns `int`, that should be implicitly converted to `float` - which suggests the problem isn't where you think it is.

- If it's not compiling, you need to show the error message
- If it's running, but not behaving the way you expect it to, you should explain *how* it's  not behaving as you expect. I strongly suspect you haven't got the data you think you have...

You've said it works if you use 100f, but that your *actual* data is 10. So maybe the problem is that the proximity alert is estimating the distance as something like 50?

Comment: @silentw: So why did you accept the answer which shows an unnecessary conversion? (By all means don't accept mine, but it seems odd to accept one which is unnecessary and just clutters up your code.)

Comment: It solved my problem that way, I figured out that the GPS coordinates weren't too close for the proximity alert to trigger. But yeah, you're right, I don't need any conversion like the one mentioned above, it's already convert using float radius (on the parameters of the function). Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

try without casting:

```
 float r = radius;
```

you don't need to convert int to float explicitly. There's an implicit conversion from float to int.

Comment: if it works when you hardcode, then above code should work. Otherwise print log and see what value is passed for radius

Comment: I logged the values, and it should work as if the integer value is 10 it is printing 10.0... But the proximity alert doesn't work :/

Comment: The problem might be in showing proximity alert.. show log if you have any exception..

Comment: It is already working, don't know why but suddenly it started working! Thanks a lot for your answer!

Comment: There's an implicit conversion from int to float, so this is unnecessary.

Comment: @SadeshkumarPeriyasamy: So why use a separate local variable? Basically, the code that's already presented should work as-is; it's just a data issue.

Answer (score 0):

float floatValue = Float.parseFloat(radius+"");

Comment: That's almost *never* a good idea. Don't use text conversions when you don't need to.

Comment: Yes, but as @silentw says, none of the above works for him (strangely), I suggested some other idea.

Comment: @silentw please make sure that you have some value in "radius". Since, all of the above solutions should work. Or, explain your question in detail.